# DataTables rows.add(array).draw() is getting called multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables

I have done this to create number of columns based on the data my server returns back. I want to check if the data in the array matches the column name, if it does then return yes else return no.

```
function initTable(userJvmsArray) {
            var columnsCallbacks = [{
                title: "Username",
                data: "username"
            }];

            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.unique.length; i++) {
                $('#nameColumn').after('<th>' + $scope.unique[i] + '</th>');
                var jvm = $scope.unique[i];
                var col = {
                    title: jvm,
                    data: function(data, type, row) {
                        var data2 = data;
                        var jvms = $scope.unique;
                        for (var k = 1; k < jvms.length; k++) {
                            console.log(jvms);
                            for (var j = 0; j < data2.myarray.length; j++) {
                                if (table.column(k).title() == data2.myarray[j].Name) {
                                    console.log(table.column(k).title() + " = " + data2.myarray[j].Name + " YES");
                                    return "yes";
                                } else {
                                console.log(table.column(k).title() + " = " + data2.myarray[j].Name + " NO");
                                    return "no";
                                }
                            }
                        }


                    }
                };
                columnsCallbacks.push(col);
                $scope.columns = columnsCallbacks;
            }
            $scope.myTable = $('#myTable').DataTable({
                'paging': true,
                "pageLength": 3,
                'columns': columnsCallbacks
            });
```

Problem is that the function seems to run more than once and populating the table incorrectly, this is my console log:

```
["myword", "secondword", fastLoop: function, fastLoopAsc: function] myctrl.controller.js:63
user1: myword = myword YES myctrl.controller.js:66
["myword", "secondword", fastLoop: function, fastLoopAsc: function] myctrl.controller.js:63
user1: myword = myword YES myctrl.controller.js:66

["myword", "secondword", fastLoop: function, fastLoopAsc: function] myctrl.controller.js:63
user11: myword = secondword NO myctrl.controller.js:69
["myword", "secondword", fastLoop: function, fastLoopAsc: function] myctrl.controller.js:63
user11: myword = secondword NO myctrl.controller.js:69

["myword", "secondword", fastLoop: function, fastLoopAsc: function] myctrl.controller.js:63
user1: myword = myword YES myctrl.controller.js:66
["myword", "secondword", fastLoop: function, fastLoopAsc: function] myctrl.controller.js:63
user11: myword = secondword NO myctrl.controller.js:69

["myword", "secondword", fastLoop: function, fastLoopAsc: function] myctrl.controller.js:63
user1: myword = myword YES myctrl.controller.js:66
["myword", "secondword", fastLoop: function, fastLoopAsc: function] myctrl.controller.js:63
user11: myword = secondword NO myctrl.controller.js:69
["myword", "secondword", fastLoop: function, fastLoopAsc: function] myctrl.controller.js:63
user1: myword = myword YES myctrl.controller.js:66
["myword", "secondword", fastLoop: function, fastLoopAsc: function] myctrl.controller.js:63
user1: myword = myword YES myctrl.controller.js:66
["myword", "secondword", fastLoop: function, fastLoopAsc: function] myctrl.controller.js:63
user11: myword = secondword NO myctrl.controller.js:69
["myword", "secondword", fastLoop: function, fastLoopAsc: function] myctrl.controller.js:63
user11: myword = secondword NO
```

Answer (score 0):

> **CAUSE**

Function for [`columns.data`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data#function) is executed multiple times because of the way DataTables works. Although it's not clear but this function might be called multiple times, as DataTables will call it for the different data types that it needs - type detection, sorting, filtering and display (`type == 'type'`, `type == 'sort'`, `type == 'filter'` and `type == 'display'`). It can also be called to set cell's data (`set == 'set'`).

Function should be defined as follows, see [`columns.data`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data#function) for more details.

```js
data: function(row, type, set, meta){ }
```

> **NOTES**

- You can use [`columns.render`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) which can be considered to be the the read-only companion to [`columns.data`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) and is less complex.
- You have a flaw in your logic with two loops, they will run only once because you immediately return `"yes"` or `"no"` value in the inner loop. I cannot correct your code because it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Is there a way for it to be called only once? Or an alternative way to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: @orange, It's not clear why you using function for `columns.data`. Do you want to just display 'yes' and 'no' in a cell under certain conditions? Also I don't see `rows.add(array).draw()` that you used in the title being used.

Comment: Yes! Thats what i want.
I'm calling draw later on. This piece of code is in a function called initTable and after this function call I do rows.add(array).draw().

Comment: @orange, can you please add the missing code with `rows.add(array)`? I think you should be using `columns.render` instead.